# how do i make simple area calculator with python and dialogflow using webhook?

Tags: python, json, api, dialogflow-es

i was trying to make an area calculator with dialog flow and python using webhook. and all i want was to return the value of the area .here is the response

```
{
  "responseId": "94e23055-2c54-42da-ba78-1f44eff8d0ab-0f0e27e1",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "find the area of 55cm and 88m",
    "parameters": {
      "unit-length": "",
      "unit-length1": {
        "unit": "cm",
        "amount": 55
      }
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/ultrabot-tlyvuq/agent/intents/b2b8e38b-6982-4b8d-8ff5-0bc42b955443",
      "displayName": "findArea"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 0.66548675,
    "diagnosticInfo": {
      "webhook_latency_ms": 357
    },
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "webhookStatus": {
    "code": 14,
    "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE."
  },
  "alternativeQueryResults": [
    {
      "queryText": "find the area of 55cm and 88m",
      "languageCode": "en"
    }
  ]
}
```

how do i make this response to return the value of the area?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it using Django framework and developed a basic arithmetic calculator. In order to perform this operations, you need to use webhook concept of dialogflow. JsonResponse returns fulfillment text back to the dialogflow.

```
@csrf_exempt
def webhook(request):
# build a request object
req = json.loads(request.body)
# get action from json
action = req.get('queryResult').get('action')
# get the arithmetic operation that needs to be done
num = req.get('queryResult').get('parameters')
n1 = int(num.get('number'))
n2 = int(num.get('number1'))
if action == 'addition':
# return a fulfillment message
    fulfillmentText = {'fulfillmentText': n1+n2}

elif action == 'subtraction':
    fulfillmentText = {'fulfillmentText': n1-n2}

elif action == 'division':
    fulfillmentText = {'fulfillmentText': n1/n2}

else:
    fulfillmentText = {'fulfillmentText': n1*n2}
# return response
return JsonResponse(fulfillmentText, safe=False)
```

Below jsonResponse will return the fulfillment text,

**return JsonResponse(fulfillmentText, safe=False)**

If you need more details, please read [my blog](https://medium.com/@mksiddhu2/calculator-chatbot-dialo-e9f8e08d07af) which provide the entire workflow that I did.